# Monero Dev XMR Address

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-setup

I created my pool but I want to make sure that my dev address is correct.  What is the Monero Dev address?

Comment: Are you referring to the address of the official development team? If so, you can see in the official website under [contributing](https://getmonero.org/get-started/contributing/)